# Python - Looping Over Specific Variables in a Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop over everything in a dictionary [1:] but don't know how to do it and can't find the answer.

```
for value in self.legLocs.itervalues():
            print x
```

And I'd think it would be something like

```
for value in self.legLocs.itervalues()[1:]:
            print x
```

But that doesn't work. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have order, so you can't really loop over all of them except the first (as which element is the first isn't really defined).  You can loop over the dict and exclude a specific key though:

```
def dict_keys_without(d,excludes_set):
    return (k for k in d if k not in excludes_set)
```

which you can then use:

```
for key in dict_keys_without(d,{'foo','bar'}):
    #do something with `k` or `d[k]`, etc.
```

And you could easily modify the above function to work with `d.iteritems()` or `d.itervalues()` or whatever criteria you want.

Of course, there's always the "Use a `collections.OrderedDict`" advice which is a dict subclass which does know it's order.  If you're using an `OrderedDict`, then you could do something like:

```
values = iter(od.values())
_ = next(values,None)  #scrap the first one
for value in values:
    pass #Do something with the next values.
```

Comment: Probably best to use `next(values, None)` so it doesn't break on empty dicts

Comment: If you need dictionary with order, you can use  [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1):

As @mgilson mentions, `[1:]` really has no meaning for a `dict`... If you're happy just ignoring some arbitrary entry, then you can use something like:

```
def skipone(d):
    i = d()
    next(i, None)
    return i

d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
for blah in skipone(d.iteritems): # or other function
    pass
```

Alternatively:

```
from itertools import islice
def skip(obj, n=1):
    i = obj() if callable(obj) else obj
    return islice(i, n, None)
```

Comment: I think I would be more likely to pass the `iter` to `skipone`.  Inside, i'd make sure I had an iterable using the `iter` builtin and I'd return the iter constructed.  e.g. `def skipone(iterable): i = iter(iterable); next(i,None); return i`.  Then it's up to the user to do `skipone(d.iteritems())`, but that extra call is a small price to pay for the increased usability in other circumstances I would think.  (But I like the idea here.  +1)

Comment: @mgilson updated to not need `iter` or `next`, takes arbitrary iterables, but keeps compatible with reading like it does now... (which IMHO reads quite nicely...)

Comment: Yeah, that's not too bad.  I like it.  At first, I thought that `callable` was deprecated, but it seems that they decided that was a bad idea and un-deprecated it after having removed it in python3.0 and 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate over all items:

```
for k,v in self.legLocs.items():
    print "key",k
    print "value",v
```

or like this:

```
for kv in self.legLocs.items():
    k, v = kv
    print "key",k
    print "value",v
```

if you want to iterate **only on keys**:

```
for k in self.legLocs.keys():
    print "key",k
```

if you want to iterate **only on values**:

```
for v in self.legLocs.values():
    print "value",v
```

Answer (score 0):

to "iterate" through a dictionary, do like this:

```
for key in aDict.keys():
    if key != 'excluded':  # You can check to see if it is the one you want to leave off
        print(aDict[key])
```